# How can I send an instance over a socket connection?

Tags: java, class, sockets, instance

I'm attempting to write two Java programs.
One to simulate a server, and one to simulate a client.

How could I go about sending an instance of a Response class over a socket?

The Response class represents status codes of the server connection. e.g. 404 Not Found etc

**I'm not allowed to use Serialisation unfortunately.**

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll always need some sort of serialization. What is the constraint exactly?

Comment: What does "I'm not allowed to use serialization" mean?  SOAP?  XML?  JSON?  You can't write your own customer serializer?  To travel over the wire, the data *must* be serialized in *some* way.

Comment: You aren't allowed to use Java Serialization? Why? Could you use custom Serialization (say, JSON on a String stream)? Also, you should consider changing the title of the question (is misleading, should say instance, not class)

Comment: I've been told that Java serialization is not to be used as the client or server end should be able to be rewritten in another programming language where java serialization isnt supported.

Comment: @James both answers below are fine then, JSON, XML, ..., they're all cross-platform serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some level Serialization must occur in order to send an object across a connection. I can only assume your comment about being not allowed to use serialization refers to not being able to use Serializable instead of a blanket prohibition of serialization(which makes no sense).  A very simple method to accomplish this would be the use of a external serialization library such as [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Gson serializes an object into a JSON string that you can transmit over your socket and then using the same library deserialize it back into an object on the other side.  You can of course use any of your preferred serialization libraries with your favorite format eg. XML, json, YAML,...

Comment: Just looked up Gson and I'm downloading the zip file now. It seems to do exactly what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be sending an instance of the Response class itself. When sending things over a network, client and server machines understand bytes. Your application can understand more than bytes, it can understand specific representations. For example, your server might send a JSON representation of your Response class like:

```
{
   "response" : {
       "code":404
   }
}
```

Then your client must be able to understand what this sequence of bytes means. That's basically what a protocol is: how two machines can communicate.

Regardless of what language the server or clients are written in, the Response is an Entity. In Java you might use a `Class` to represent it, in C++ you might use a `struct`. However, both would need to know that when you are communicating with an external application.system, they would have to put it in a format that everyone understands, be it json, xml, or any other.

As for sending this through sockets, Oracle has a nice [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html). You get the `OutputStream`
from the socket and start writing your representation.